# How make always ask permissions geolocation webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, maps

I create an application android for maps, but I want the application **always ask** permissions geolocation on the webview...any idea? Thanks

**WebChromeClient**

```
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }
```

**Settings Web View**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("https://maps.google.com");
```

**Manifest file Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Solution

I change This

```
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}
```

to

```
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin, final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()");

            final boolean remember = false;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Locations Permission");
            builder.setMessage("Would like to use your Current Location ")
                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // origin, allow, remember
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Don't Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // origin, allow, remember
                    callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Done

Comment: For this part new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this) it says error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I found that if GeoWebChromeClient located in another file then it can't access to MainActivity class. So I have to pass it via constructor when initiate GeoWebChromeClient

Comment: Note that this does show the alert dialog but does not give the application sufficient geolocation permission.